# R: find vector in list of vectors

Tags: r, list, vector, find

i'm working with R and my goal is to check wether a given vector is in a list of unique vectors.

The list looks like

```
final_states <- list(c("x" = 5, "y" = 1),
                 c("x" = 5, "y" = 2),
                 c("x" = 5, "y" = 3),
                 c("x" = 5, "y" = 4),
                 c("x" = 5, "y" = 5),
                 c("x" = 3, "y" = 5))
```

Now I want to check wether a given state is in the list. For example:

```
state <- c("x" = 5, "y" = 3)
```

As you can see, the vector state is an element of the list final_states. My idea was to check it with %in% operator:

```
state %in% final_states
```

But I get this result:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

Can anyone tell me, what is wrong?

Greets,
lupi

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to determine if the vector is in the list, try

```
Position(function(x) identical(x, state), final_states, nomatch = 0) > 0
# [1] TRUE
```

`Position()` basically works like `match()`, but on a list. If you set `nomatch = 0` and check for `Position > 0`, you'll get a logical result telling you whether `state` is in `final_states`

Comment: This is a nice solution in a single line. In another place in code I have to determine the index of the vector. I can use the `Position()` function, too. Thank you ;-)

Comment: @lupi5 - you're welcome.  There is also `Find()`, which returns the first or last match

Comment: I tried `%in%` with `lapply` and got what I thought were misleading results. I am thinking `Position` was more analogous to `which`.

Comment: I did too. Since this returns the position of the first or last match, it should safely check whether `state` is in the list

Answer (score 8):

"final_states" is a "list", so you could convert the "state" to `list` and then do

```
final_states %in% list(state)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

or use `mapply` to check whether all the elements in "state" are present in each of the list elements of "final_states" (assuming that the lengths are the same for the vector and the list elements)

```
 f1 <- function(x,y) all(x==y)
 mapply(f1, final_states, list(state))
 #[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Or `rbind` the list elements to a matrix and then check whether "state" and the "rows" of "m1" are the same.

```
m1 <- do.call(rbind, final_states)
!rowSums(m1!=state[col(m1)])
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Or

```
 m1[,1]==state[1] & m1[,2]==state[2]
 #[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

#### Update

If you need to get a single `TRUE/FALSE`

```
  any(mapply(f1, final_states, list(state)))
  #[1] TRUE
```

Or

```
  any(final_states %in% list(state))
  #[1] TRUE
```

Or

```
 list(state) %in% final_states
 #[1] TRUE
```

Or use the "faster" `fmatch` from `fastmatch`

```
 library(fastmatch)
 fmatch(list(state), final_states) >0
 #[1] TRUE
```

#### Benchmarks

@Richard Sciven's `base R` function is very fast compared to other solutions except the one with `fmatch`

```
 set.seed(295)
 final_states <- replicate(1e6, sample(1:20, 20, replace=TRUE), 
          simplify=FALSE)
 state <- final_states[[151]]


 richard <- function() {Position(function(x) identical(x, state),
              final_states, nomatch = 0) > 0}
 Bonded <- function(){any( sapply(final_states, identical, state) )}
 akrun2 <- function() {fmatch(list(state), final_states) >0}
 akrun1 <- function() {f1 <- function(x,y) all(x==y)
            any(mapply(f1, final_states, list(state)))}

 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(richard(), Bonded(), akrun1(), akrun2(), 
        unit='relative', times=20L)
 #Unit: relative
 #    expr          min           lq        mean      median          uq
 # richard()     35.22635     29.47587    17.49164    15.66833    14.58235
 # Bonded() 109440.56885 101382.92450 55252.86141 47734.96467 44289.80309
 # akrun1() 167001.23864 138812.85016 75664.91378 61417.59871 62667.94867
 # akrun2()      1.00000      1.00000     1.00000     1.00000     1.00000
  #          max neval cld
  #     14.62328    20 a  
  #  46299.43325    20 b 
  #  63890.68133    20 c
  #      1.00000    20 a
```

Comment: Is there a simple OR-like method to evaluate the resulting boolean-vector? I think about something like or(mapply(f1, final_states, list(state))) => TRUE

Comment: @lupi5 You can try `any(mapply(f1, final_states, list(state)))`

Comment: I found the following solution: sum(mapply(...)) > 0

Comment: @lupi5 yes, there are many ways to do this.  Glad you found `sum`

Comment: @lupi5 I think `list(state) %in% final_states` would get you the single `TRUE/FALSE`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, akrun! I learned a lot. Espacially the solutions with simple use of `list(state) %in% final_states` and the fast `fmatch()`-function are very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever i see a list object I first think of `lapply`. Seems to deliver the expected result with `identical` as the test and 'state' as the second argument:

```
> lapply(final_states, identical, state)
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE

[[4]]
[1] FALSE

[[5]]
[1] FALSE

[[6]]
[1] FALSE
```

You get a possibly useful intermediate result with:

```
lapply(final_states, match, state)
```

... but it comes back as a series of position vectors where c(1,2) is the correct result.

If you want the result to come back as a vector , say for instance you want to use `any`, then use `sapply` instead of `lapply`.

```
> any( sapply(final_states[-3], identical, state) )
[1] FALSE
> any( sapply(final_states, identical, state) )
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: also a nice solution! Thank you. Is there a way to output just TRUE if one or more entries are TRUE? Like `any(lapply(...))`?

Comment: You technically can use `any(lapply...)` in the final block of code, but it throws a warning because of `any`'s coercion from list to logical vector. In truth, `sapply` is also coercing, but isn't warning you about it. Your mileage may vary as to which of those two options is worse. The "safe" way to do what you've done is to use `any(vapply(final_states, identical, state, FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))`, but that's quite verbose.