# Filtering a list of lists based on list combinations - R

Tags: r

I have a list of lists:

```
library(partitions)
list_parts(3)

>[1] (1,2,3)
>[[2]]
>[1] (1,3)(2)
>[[3]]
>[1] (1,2)(3)
>[[4]]
>[1] (2,3)(1)
>[[5]]
>[1] (1)(2)(3)
```

I need to filter out certain lists based on combinations as they are not feasible. For example list[4] is not possible because (2,3) cannot be a list without (1). How can I filter based on a combination rule set eg remove combinations where 2 and 3 are in a list without 1?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/8485403) and expected outcome. I'll venture you can probably use regex, but I'm not familiar with this class of data.

Comment: It's a list of lists... tricky. I would say it's *almost* a dupe of [Find vector in list of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28254164/903061)

Answer (score 0):

We can borrow the method from [this answer to Find vector in list of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28254318/903061) and wrap it in our own function.

```
library(partitions)
p = listParts(3)

detect = function(p, pattern) {
  Position(function(x) identical(x, pattern), p, nomatch = 0) > 0
}

test = sapply(p, detect, pattern = 2:3)
p[!test]
# [[1]]
# [1] (1,2,3)
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] (1,3)(2)
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] (1,2)(3)
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] (1)(2)(3)
```