# R - remove word from a sentence

Tags: r, string

I have a vector in R which has a list of words at the last index of vector. I need to remove some words out of that list

```
sentence <- "This is a sample sentence with words like or to be removed"
wordsToRemove <- c("The","an", "very", "of", "or","in","a","uses","that","be")

splitSent <- strsplit(sentence, " ")
```

I tried `wordsToRemove %in% list(splitSent)` but that gives all false. Is there any other way to handle it?

Note: the sentence is an element in my vector which has int, other data types as well. And I have gone through below link
[R: find vector in list of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254164/r-find-vector-in-list-of-vectors)

Comment: You may need `splitSent[[1]][!splitSent[[1]] %in% wordsToRemove]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using `sub` here with a regex alternation to cover all your terms.  This answer works by searching for the following regex, and then replacing it with empty string to effectively remove it:

```
\s*\b(The|an|very|of|or|in|a|uses|that|be)\b
```

This will match any of your terms, along with any amount of leading whitespace.

```
sentence <- "This is a sample sentence with words like or to be removed"
sentence
wordsToRemove <- c("The","an", "very", "of", "or","in","a","uses","that","be")

regex <- paste0("\\s*\\b(", paste(wordsToRemove, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
output <- sub("^\\s+", "", gsub(regex, "", sentence, ignore.case=TRUE))
output

[1] "This is a sample sentence with words like or to be removed"
[1] "This is sample sentence with words like to removed"
```

Note that I actually make an additional call to `sub` above, because we have to trim any initial leading whitespace which the pattern might miss.

Comment: Based on OP's comment above, might want to point out the `ignore.case = TRUE` option.

Comment: How does this change if sentence is a part of vector and I want to do this for all the values of sentence in the vector

Comment: @Ankit That sounds like the second time you have changed your question, so I'm not willing to update at this point.  If you have this additional need, you should ask another question.

Comment: @Tim, The question always started with "I have a vector in R which has a list of words at the last index of vector". Apologies for the confusion but the sentence was just an example

Comment: Then maybe I don't understand your question.  You should make an update if you left something out.

Comment: Same thing is in the Note as well "Note: the sentence is an element in my vector which has int, other data types as well."